# w3 total cache wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, кэширование, плагин

Включил плагин и что-то наклацал, до ошибок в консоле. После очистил кеш и удалил плагин w3 total cache, а ошибки остались. Как вернуть в первоначальное состояние (до установки плагина w3 total cache)?
Ошибки, так полагаю, из-за минимизации, например, ругает на знак $ при использовании jQuery:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После удаления плагина он никак не влияет на текущее состояние сайта. Так что наклацали вы в другом месте.

Comment: Какие ошибки? Тексты ошибок - в тело вопроса!

Comment: @KAGGDesign может и влиять. Следов кеш-плаги оставляют порядочно. Особенно при неумелом обращении с ними и их удалении.

Comment: Прежде чем устанавливать сторонние плагины, нужно всегда делать бекап БД. Так как плагины все-таки могут влиять на систему, оставляя или изменяя записи в БД, которые не всегда корректно удаляются.

Comment: Верни прошлый .htaccess